# Alternate to Like in jsonb postgres

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

I have a Postgres table with more than 25M records, there I have a jsonb column called info.

sample json format:

```
{
"username1":{"name":"somename","age":22,"gender":"male"},
"fathername":{"name":"somename","age":22,"gender":"male"}
}
```

I am going to find number of records that match the 'user%' key value.

Here is my query

```
select count(1) from tablename where info::text like '%user%';
```

this query is working and I am getting result for it, but it is taking long time to execute this query in 25M records.

Is there any way that I can optimize this query or any alternate method to achieve it? Please help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The query always yields 0.

Answer (score 0):

As @klin as pointed out, this query will only give you 0:

```
select count(1) from tablename where info::text like 'user%';
```

Why because this is just a simple pattern match and you don't have any strings in your info column that begins with 'user'. You might have better luck with '%user%' but that's going to be awfully slow (unless you have trigram extension enabled and an index created)

If you want to count exactly how many users have the `username1` set it's a really simple query.

```
select count(1) from tablename where info ? 'username1'
```

This works on [9.5](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html). If you have a finite number of 'user%' keywords, you can try something like this:

```
select count(1) from tablename where info ?| array['username1','username2',..]
```

If you are uncertain about the nature of the keys then you can do

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM (
    SELECT * FROM JSONB_EACH(info) FROM tablename
) AS a WHERE a.key like '%user%'
```

Comment: sorry I meant '%user%', and from the above queries I can find the count if I know the exact key text, here I didnt know the exact text, that is the reason why I am using like.

Comment: what I meant is I cannot give info ? 'username1', cause I dont know the exact text(username1), what I have got is only 'user', with that I need to get all records that starts with 'user' in the json. Hope this clears!

Comment: Yes I did, this is taking mostly the same time as "like", I did not see big difference between them.

Comment: If you are forcing yourself to use wildcards it will be slower than using constants. I have mentioned that in my answer.

Comment: You have a poorly designed database the only way to speed it up would be normalize it. If you know what you are searching for the queries can be optimized, if you don't - well sorry no

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks ugly, but I think this could work:

```
select count(1) from (
    -- unnest an array of keys
    select id, unnest(array_agg(d.k)) as k from (
        -- extract info keys
        select id, jsonb_object_keys(info) as k from tablename
    ) as d
    where k like '%user%'
    group by id
) as q
group by id;
```